# How do I map a substring in Automapper?

Tags: automapper

I have a string called policy.  Value is AAC1234567XX.  How do I use automapper to pull out and map only positions 4 - 10 to another column called PolicyNo?

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you've tried so far, (source code) and then an explanation on the specific error/problem your encountering

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a custom resolver when you define the mapping - something like this:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Left, Right>()
    .ForMember(right => right.PolicyNo, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(left => left.Policy.Substring(3, 6)));
```

This basically specifies that the `PolicyNo` property on the object being mapped to is resolved using the function which substrings the `Policy` property on the object being mapped from.